# Codeigniter calendar customization

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar

I have set up the events calendar using default codeigniter calendar. I just couldnt figure out a way to customize it. followed the guide and used the same template and modified the look with css.
I also followed tutorial from http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-the-calendar-library/

Problem is I want to add more functionality like having a drop down to navigate to different month and year instead of clicking next all the way. And also I want next and previous button next to each other rather than at corners of the calendar. I tried rearranging the template code but of no use.

I want something similar to this
http://davidwalsh.name/demo/php-calendar-controls.php

The template code I have used is

```
$prefs['template'] = '

           {table_open}<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">{/table_open}

           {heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}

           {heading_previous_cell}<th><a href="{previous_url}">&lt;&lt;</a></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
           {heading_title_cell}<th colspan="{colspan}">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}
           {heading_next_cell}<th><a href="{next_url}">&gt;&gt;</a></th>{/heading_next_cell}

           {heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}

           {week_row_start}<tr>{/week_row_start}
           {week_day_cell}<td>{week_day}</td>{/week_day_cell}
           {week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}

           {cal_row_start}<tr class="calendar_days">{/cal_row_start}
           {cal_cell_start}<td>{/cal_cell_start}

           {cal_cell_content}
                <div class="calendar_day_num">{day}</div>
                <div class="calendar_content">{content}</div>
           {/cal_cell_content}
           {cal_cell_content_today}
                <div class="calendar_day_num calendar_highlight">{day}</div>
                <div class="calendar_content">{content}</div>
           {/cal_cell_content_today}

           {cal_cell_no_content}<div class="calendar_day_num">{day}</div>{/cal_cell_no_content}
           {cal_cell_no_content_today}<div class="calendar_day_num calendar_highlight">{day}</div>{/cal_cell_no_content_today}

           {cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}

           {cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}
           {cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}

           {table_close}</table>{/table_close}
        ';
```

There is nothing wrong with the template but I want to have something like

```
$prefs['template'] = '

           {table_open}<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">{/table_open}

           {heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}

           {heading_previous_cell}<th><a href="{year_month}"><!--dropdown for year and month--></a></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
           {heading_title_cell}<th colspan="{colspan}">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}
            {heading_previous_cell}<th><a href="{previous_url}">&lt;&lt;</a></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
           {heading_next_cell}<th><a href="{next_url}">&gt;&gt;</a></th>{/heading_next_cell}

           {heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}

           {week_row_start}<tr>{/week_row_start}
           {week_day_cell}<td>{week_day}</td>{/week_day_cell}
           {week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}
```

So the output will be

1. 1st column - Heading (that is month name)
2. 2nd column - drop down option for easy navigation to a particular year & a month
3. 3rd column - links for next & previous month

Comment: Could you post up some example code up or explain a bit more about what you've tried?

Comment: Sorry had a busy week updated my question.